# python/selenium/chromedriver TimeoutException

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm in the process of scraping pdfs from a website using selenium and chrome webdriver. I use the following, pulling the `site` from a list:

```
driver.get(site) 
source = driver.page_source
...
...
driver.quit()
```

But I keep getting the following error, about 6,000 observations down my `site` list:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 127, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 323, in get self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 311, in execute self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 237, in check_response raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: timeout
(Session info: chrome=63.0.3239.84)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506092 
(733a02544d189eeb751fe0d7ddca79a0ee28cce4),platform=Linux 4.10.0-40-generic x86_64)
```

I've tried refreshing the source page at shorter intervals (every 200 searches, but should I go shorter?).

How do I extend selenium's 120sec timeout limit?

Comment: Usually the `timeout` occurs when you are trying to navigate to a page and the page does not respond within the allowed time. Please share your **code** and the **HTML** or **URL** of the page you are scraping so someone can answer with confidence. I am a little confused as to what you are trying to achieve when this `timeout` occurs.

Comment: I'm guessing that `driver.set_page_load_timeout(121)` is the way to do it.

Comment: Does this require JS calls, or can you just grab what you want via HTTP requests? If so, they will save you ungodly amounts of time.

Answer (score 2):

This error message...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 127, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 323, in get self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
.
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: timeout
(Session info: chrome=63.0.3239.84)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506092 
(733a02544d189eeb751fe0d7ddca79a0ee28cce4),platform=Linux 4.10.0-40-generic x86_64)
```

...implies that the *webdriver* instance cannot establish a connection with the **site** `url` and *timeout* occurs.

Your main issue is the **version compatibility** between the binaries you are using as follows :

- You are using **ChromeDriver v2.33**
- Release Notes of [**ChromeDriver v2.33**](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.33/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> **Supports Chrome v60-62**

- You are using **chrome=63.0**
- **Selenium Version** is unknown to us.

So there is a clear mismatch between the **ChromeDriver v2.33** and the **Chrome Browser v63.0** you are using. Hence **ChromeDriver** is unable to spawn the new *Chrome Browser* process.

### Solution

- Update *ChromeDriver* to recent  **v2.35** level.
- Upgrade *Chrome* to  stable **Chrome v64.x** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.35 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.35/notes.txt))
- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels **Version 3.9.1**.
- *Clean* and *Re-Build* your project through your *IDE*.
- Clear the *Browser Cache*.
- Run [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after execution of your *Test Suite*.
- If your *Web Browser* base version is too old, uninstall the *Web Browser* through [Revo Uninstaller](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) with *Moderate Scan* and install a recent **GA Released** version of the *Web Browser*.
- Execute your *Tests*.