# How to change the input field value using Selenium and Python

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriverwait

I am trying to change the input field value in a form input, but unable to do so.

Input value is at this [URL](https://primexbt.com/my/trade)

`Email: Vela.admi@gmail.com`
`PW: Testing@123`

On the page form appears after these actions:

```
1. on left side click on "Sell Order" red button in Dashboard widget
2. a popup will appear on click, select "Order Type" as "Limit"
3. a new formfield appears, named "Limit Price"
```

[image: Required Field]
 When I try to change it using selenium or even if JS, it doesn't seem to change when we submit the form by pressing "Send Order"

My code trails are:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time

driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#gwt-uid-770 > span > span > input').send_keys('6700')
```

I have also tried

```
driver.execute_script("document.querySelector('#gwt-uid-770 > span > span > input').value=6700")
```

But still when I submit it doesn't seem to change.

Comment: Website require login. can you share if its for testing purpose or share the HTML of element

Comment: @NarendraR editing the question to add credentials

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To perform the following steps:

1. On left side click on "Sell Order" red button in Dashboard widget
2. A popup will appear on click, select "Order Type" as "Limit"
3. A new formfield appears, named "Limit Price"
4. Send the value `10000` to the `<input>` field.

You have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
  from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get('https://primexbt.com/id/sign-in?redirect=%2Fmy%2Ftrade')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[formcontrolname='email']"))).send_keys("Vela.admi@gmail.com")
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[formcontrolname='password']").send_keys("Testing@123")
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.mat-button-wrapper").click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.popup-close"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe.ng-star-inserted")))
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.price.price-bid"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='selectBox--label' and text()='Market']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//ul[@class='dropDown--list']//li[contains(., 'Limit')]"))).click()
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[text()='Limit Price']//following::span[1]//span[@class='numericStepper--input']//input[@class='gwt-TextBox']")))
  ActionChains(driver).click(element).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys("a").key_up(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys("10000").perform()
  ```
- **Note**: At the time of constructing the answer:

> Entry Price you set must be higher or equal to 9786.7

- Browser Snapshot:

[image: primaxbt]

Comment: can you explain what `WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable` does. In 10 to 12 trails, it failed 8-9 times, before it, i used time.sleep which showed better results

Comment: @curious_nustian See the discussion [How to get rid of the hardcoded sleep()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54637664/how-to-get-rid-of-the-hardcoded-sleep/54637793#54637793) to understand why not to use `time.sleep()` and [WebDriverWait not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) discussion for `element_to_be_clickable`

Comment: what can be cause of `raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)` despite the element is visible

Comment: _WebDriverWait_ ignores [NoSuchElementException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294) and on timeout raises [TimeoutException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48916783/python-selenium-chromedriver-timeoutexception/48920865#48920865)

Answer (score 2):

While inspecting the require element i found that there is an iframe on which the content wrapped.

[image]

So to deal with frames in selenium first you need to switch into right iframe and then it allows you to interact with the elements.

1. Switch using iframe indexes

   ```
   driver.switch_to.frame(0)
   ```
2. Switch using iframe element

   ```
   main_frame = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('iframe.ng-star-inserted')
   driver.switch_to.frame(main_frame)
   ```
3. Switch using iframe name

   ```
   driver.switch_to.frame('frame name') #make sure name attribute available in frame tag
   ```

This is how you can use Explicit wait condition to switch into it

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 45).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe.ng-star-inserted")))
```

And use this locator to enter text in texxtbox

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(.,'Limit Price')]/following-sibling::span//input").send_keys('6700')
```