# Javascript button wit no id not clicking with Selenium (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to click on the following button using Selenium in Python. However, any way I have tried to approach clicking on that button has failed and I was hoping someone could help. For all intents and purposes. I am a novice in both Python/Selenium so any help would be greatly appreciated!

```html
<tr> 
  <td colspan=3></td>
  <td align=center valign='center'> <a href="javascript:myFunction('/mailbox/jsp/MBIList.jsp')"
      onMouseOver="chgButton('Go','GoOver'); window.status=''; return true;"
      onMouseOut="chgButton('Go','GoOff'); window.status=''; return true;"
      onMouseDown="chgButton('Go','GoDown'); return true;"><img border=0
      src="/mailbox/images/go_off.gif" vspace=7 name='Go' align='top'></a> 
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please share what all methods you have tried. It will be easy to see issue if you share your code rather than guessing it.

Answer (score 0):

U can click on any element using any of the element attributes. For example in this case I would use attribute @name='Go' in your **Xpath**, where you are trying to select element.

Answer (score 0):

The desired element is a dynamic element, so to click on the element you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href*='/mailbox/jsp/MBIList'] > img[name='Go'][src^='/mailbox/images/go_off']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@href, '/mailbox/jsp/MBIList')]/img[@name='Go' and starts-with(@src, '/mailbox/images/go_off')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thank you! Am getting the same timeout error:

selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: @yms111 To address [TimeoutException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48916783/python-selenium-chromedriver-timeoutexception/48920865#48920865) check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63014684/selenium-common-exceptions-timeoutexception-error-using-webdriverwait-with-expec/63020121#63020121) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50843483/selenium-common-exceptions-timeoutexception-while-invoking-click-on-an-elemen/50853898#50853898) discussion.